# Getting text to spread to the edge of the div

Tags: html, css

I want to get the text in the green div ‘header-text-wrap’ to neatly spread to the edge of the div. I know it can work with the letter spacing and word spacing commands, but I am worried about compatibility if I did it this way (if some browsers displayed the font at a slightly different size, then the text would resize incorrectly or add another unwanted line). If I use the justify command, only the top line is perfectly spaced but not the line below.

Can this be achieved without having a fixed div width with word and letter spacing?

Thank you for any help

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
 background-color:#F6F7C1; 
 padding:0px;
 margin:0 auto; /* aligns content to touch the edge; gets rid of default spacing/margin between edge and content */
}

/* Header */
#header-wrap{
 background:#D6ECFF;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #CCC;
 /* margin:0 auto; needed? */
}
#header-top{
 /* contains logo & title text */
 width:960px;
 height:auto;
 margin:0 auto; /* aligns centrally */
 /* the below aligns the divs centrally (vertically & horizontally) */
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.header-top-content-wrap{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
 padding:15px 0 10px 0;
 /* the below aligns the divs centrally (vertically & horizontally) */
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.header-text-wrap{
 width:460px;
 height:auto;
 text-align:justify;
 float:left;
 background:#090;
}
.header-logo-wrap{
 width:190px;
 height:100px;
 text-align:justify;
 float:left;
 padding-right:30px;
}
#header-bottom{
 /* contains navigation menu */
 width:960px;
 height:auto;
 margin:0 auto; /* aligns centrally */
 padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
 /* the below aligns the divs centrally (vertically & horizontally) */
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.header-navigation-link{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 margin-right: 50px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif, tahoma, Arial, Cambria;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 color:#333;
}
.header-navigation-link-end{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 margin-right: 0px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif, tahoma, Arial, Cambria;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 color:#333;
}

/* Fonts */
header{
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif, tahoma, Arial, Cambria;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 font-size:45px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 line-height:40px;
 color:#000;
}
slogan{
 font-family: courier new, tahoma, Arial, Cambria, serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 font-size:20px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 word-spacing:10px;
 letter-spacing:5px;
 color:#666;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<!-- Meta Tags Below -->
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<title>___________________________</title>
<!-- Google Analytics Code Below -->
<!-- _____________________________ -->
</head>

<body>

<!-- Header -->
<!-- #BeginLibraryItem "/Library/header.lbi" -->
<div id="header-wrap">
  <div id="header-top">
    <div class="header-top-content-wrap">
      <div class="header-logo-wrap"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="190" height="100"  alt="logo"/></div>
      <div class="header-text-wrap">
        <header>first line of text &amp; second line</header>
        <slogan>slogan goes here too</slogan>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="header-bottom">
    <div class="header-navigation-link">Home</div>
    <div class="header-navigation-link">About</div>
    <div class="header-navigation-link">Services</div>
    <div class="header-navigation-link-end">Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- #EndLibraryItem -->

<!-- Main -->
<div id="body-wrap">body</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This may help: http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Comment: the font size needs to be fixed, and text justified (with the bottom line also justified)

Answer (score 0):

Add these CSS declarations to your `header-text-wrap` class:

```
text-align: justify;  
-moz-text-align-last: justify; /* For Firefox */
text-align-last: justify;
```

Like this:

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
 background-color:#F6F7C1; 
 padding:0px;
 margin:0 auto; /* aligns content to touch the edge; gets rid of default spacing/margin between edge and content */
}

/* Header */
#header-wrap{
 background:#D6ECFF;
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 border-bottom: 3px solid #CCC;
 /* margin:0 auto; needed? */
}
#header-top{
 /* contains logo & title text */
 width:960px;
 height:auto;
 margin:0 auto; /* aligns centrally */
 /* the below aligns the divs centrally (vertically & horizontally) */
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.header-top-content-wrap{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
 padding:15px 0 10px 0;
 /* the below aligns the divs centrally (vertically & horizontally) */
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.header-text-wrap{
 width:460px;
 height:auto;
 text-align:justify;
 float:left;
 background:#090;
    text-align: justify;  
    -moz-text-align-last: justify; /* For Firefox */
    text-align-last: justify;
}
.header-logo-wrap{
 width:190px;
 height:100px;
 text-align:justify;
 float:left;
 padding-right:30px;
}
#header-bottom{
 /* contains navigation menu */
 width:960px;
 height:auto;
 margin:0 auto; /* aligns centrally */
 padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
 /* the below aligns the divs centrally (vertically & horizontally) */
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
.header-navigation-link{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 margin-right: 50px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif, tahoma, Arial, Cambria;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 color:#333;
}
.header-navigation-link-end{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 float:left;
 margin-right: 0px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif, tahoma, Arial, Cambria;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 color:#333;
}

/* Fonts */
header{
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif, tahoma, Arial, Cambria;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 font-size:45px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 line-height:40px;
 color:#000;
}
slogan{
 font-family: courier new, tahoma, Arial, Cambria, serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* subtley makes fonts smoother */
 font-size:20px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 word-spacing:10px;
 letter-spacing:5px;
 color:#666;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
<!-- Meta Tags Below -->
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<title>___________________________</title>
<!-- Google Analytics Code Below -->
<!-- _____________________________ -->
</head>

<body>

<!-- Header -->
<!-- #BeginLibraryItem "/Library/header.lbi" -->
<div id="header-wrap">
  <div id="header-top">
    <div class="header-top-content-wrap">
      <div class="header-logo-wrap"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="190" height="100"  alt="logo"/></div>
      <div class="header-text-wrap">
        <header>first line of text &amp; second line</header>
        <slogan>slogan goes here too</slogan>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="header-bottom">
    <div class="header-navigation-link">Home</div>
    <div class="header-navigation-link">About</div>
    <div class="header-navigation-link">Services</div>
    <div class="header-navigation-link-end">Contact</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- #EndLibraryItem -->

<!-- Main -->
<div id="body-wrap">body</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: That only justifies the first line. It's difficult to explain, but I'm trying to also spread the 2nd and third lines to the edge of the div.

Comment: I have tried it on Chrome, Mozilla and Edge and all three lines were justified like this: http://pasteboard.co/hExF5mwfn.png

Comment: that looks correct but it doesn't look like that on my browser. do you know of the same attribute '-moz-text-align-last: justify;' but for safari / all browsers?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that there is no such thing for Safari and Opera. Maybe you could use JavaScript or even Angular to solve that.